# How to create in the first row of a data frame the total sum of a column

Tags: r, dplyr

strong text
I would like to create in the first row the total sum of a column. This is an example of the structure I want to do.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiPLN.png)

In this file you can find the data frame df_calculo
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wSEgG_SRa5PSCWaIiFF_ceXqDDSdjsW0/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114987901932393085623&rtpof=true&sd=true

So far, I have this code:

```
data_informe<-df_calculo %>%
  filter(Tipo=="Bovinos", Periodo=="2022") %>% 
  group_by(Departamento, Periodo) %>% 
  summarize(Total = sum(Total))%>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=Periodo, values_from = Total, 
              names_prefix=paste("Año corrido a", mes, " "))
```

To generate this row I try this code:

```
data_informe<-rbind(c("Total Bovinos", sum(data_informe[,2])),
                    data_informe)
```

But I get this error:

Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Argument 1 must have names.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Your code shows `rbind` and not bind_rows.  Please show a small reproducible example.  Try with `rbind(list(Tip = "Total Bovinos", ...` a named list or data.frame

Comment: I try this, but I get the same error:  
data_informe<-rbind(list(Tip = "Total Bovinos", sum(data_informe[,2])),
                        data_informe)

Comment: The `sum` also should match a column name because `rbind` looks for matching column names

Comment: I just added an example of the dataframe in the post

Answer (score 1):

The `janitor` package has a nice function to do exactly that, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(kableExtra)
df <- readxl::read_excel("Book1.xlsx")
df %>% 
  filter(Tipo=="Bovinos", Periodo=="2022") %>% 
  group_by(Departamento, Periodo) %>% 
  summarize(Total = sum(Total)) %>% 
  select(-Periodo) %>% 
  mutate(Total = replace_na(Total, 0)) %>% 
  janitor::adorn_totals(name = "Total bolivianos") %>% 
  slice(n(), 1:n()-1) %>% 
  kbl(col.names = c("", ""), format = "html") %>% 
  add_header_above(c("", "2022" = 1)) %>% 
  add_header_above(c("", "Ano corrido a Mayo" = 1)) %>% 
  row_spec(1, bold = T) %>% 
  column_spec(2, border_left = T, border_right = T) %>% 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "condensed", full_width = F)
```

Output:

[image: example table]

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of reproducible data, here's a solution with toy data:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                 name = letters[1:10])
```

Solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  summarise(across(name, first),
            x = sum(x)) %>%
  mutate(name = "Total") %>%
  bind_rows(., df)
    name  x
1  Total 55
2      a  1
3      b  2
4      c  3
5      d  4
6      e  5
7      f  6
8      g  7
9      h  8
10     i  9
11     j 10
```